# Neither pidgin or empathy receive offline Gmail chat messages

Tags: empathy, pidgin

I can't recive any offline message from Gmail chat.
I need to get them.

I set up pidgin and empathy whith my Gmail account, but they only receive messages when I am online.

What do I do?

Comment: I can recive message when I am online only.

Comment: This bug is not actually an issue on the Ubuntu side of things.  This is a bug in the Google side of things.

Comment: But then the question is relevant to Ubuntu and the answer is that it's a bug on Google's side of things? Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 6):

This is broken on the side of Google. See this [discussion](http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chat/XqQKYLbTeZ8/discussion), we are not alone:

You have to go to gmail to see unread offline messages. They call this an improvement.

Answer (score -1):

How can you receive messages when you are not online?

Maybe you intended in Invisible mode?

Since the introduction of Hangouts instead of GMail chat there is no more the status of Invisible.

If you are offline the messages your contacts send to you will be dispatched when you connect to the service.

Comment: I want to send me offline message after I connected to internet.How to intend in visible mode,if I intended in Invisible mode?What I do?   sorry for my bad English:(

Comment: My English is not so good too. You do want something like "You are offline. Someone send you a message. Two days after you get online, this message is delivered to you." Did I understand it right?

Comment: I think user11008 is able to receive messages when he and the other party are both offilne. However, when the other sends something when user11008 is offline, the chat will appear in gmail interface, but they will never make it to pidgin, even after it gets online again. Do I understand it correctly? I found something about it here: https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chat/XqQKYLbTeZ8/discussion - it is a bug or feature in google"s implementation.